# C: Can't seem to find the bug [Do-While loop]

Tags: c, loops, do-while

The program is simple:

1) It accepts the user's name
2) Asks how many items he has purchased and how much it costs
3) if the inputs anything > 10 items, it says "please enter a number greater than 0 (zero) and less than 10 (ten). Do you want to continue generating another bill? (Y/N)"
4) The user inputs 'Y', it is supposed to take him to the beginning of the do loop and start over.

Everything in between is working fine. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    char item[10][10], answer = 'null', name[10];
    int price[10], total_item, total_price = 0, i, j = 0, a;
    float service_tax = 0, vat = 0,total_bill = 0,  bill = 0;

    printf ("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf ("%s", name);

    do
    {
        printf ("\n Enter the total items purchased (must be more than 0 (zero) and less than 10 (ten): ");
        scanf (" %d", &total_item);

        if(total_item > 0 && total_item <= 10)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < total_item; i++)
        {
            printf ("\nEnter the item name: ");
            scanf ("%s", item[i]);

            printf ("\nEnter the item price: ");
            scanf ("%d", &price[i]);

            bill = bill + price[i];
        }

        printf("You bill WITHOUT the tax is: %f \n", bill);

        service_tax = ((bill * 10)/100);
        vat = ((bill * 12)/100);

        total_bill = service_tax + vat + bill;

        printf("The items you've purchased are: \n");
        for(i = 0; i < total_item; i++)
        {
            printf("\n%s - %d\n", item[i], price[i]);
        }

        printf("Your total bill is: %3f", total_bill);

        printf ("Your bill# is %s-%d-%d", &name, total_item, rand()%1000);  
    }

    else
    {
        printf("\n %s, please enter a number greater than 0 (zero) and less than 10 (ten)", &name);

        printf("\nDo you want to continue generating another bill? (Y/N)\n");
        scanf (" %c", &answer);
    }

}while ((answer == 'y') || (answer = 'Y'));

return 0;}
```

Please PLEASE HELP ME! For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out why the do-while loop isn't working.

You help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: answer = 'Y' change to answer == 'Y'

Comment: `answer = 'Y'` in the `while` clause is suspicious, you meant `answer == 'Y'`?

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
while ((answer == 'y') || (answer = 'Y'));
```

is using `=` when it meant `==`. The above condition will always be true, since `'Y'` is not zero.

Some people prevent themselves from having this problem by always writing the variable on the right hand side, i.e. the above would have been (correctly) written as

```
while (('y' == answer) || ('Y' == answer));
```

When written like that, if you miss one `=` you get an error since the literal on the left is not assignable.

I dislike this, I find it hard to read. It also breaks down when comparing two variables, which is not uncommon.

Comment: ...something that proper use of compiler warnings would have told you about.

Comment: ...although I have the warning switched off and believe I'm not alone in doing that. Assignment within `if` is perfectly acceptable and frequently used in math code.

Answer (score 0):

Typo. You have `answer = 'Y'` but you meant `answer == 'Y'`.

Some folk write `'Y' == answer` as a course of habit, since an errant `'Y' = answer` will cause a **compile time** failure.

Answer (score -1):

Changed while to while ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'));

It worked. And I am not a dude..

Comment: Yes you are `Anonymous Person`